# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' to '(Swift.String, UIImage, Swift.String)'

Tags: swift3

I have a collection of tuples called services:

```
let services = [
    (name: "iCloud",   image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iCloudLogo"), url: "http://www.icloud.com"),
    (name: "Exchange", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ExchangeLogo"), url: "http://www.exchange.com")
]
```

I have a collection view which I use to represent this collection. I use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let service = services[indexPath.item]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showAuthWindow", sender: service)
}
```

from the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol to capture taps on these items and perform a segue, passing the individual tuple as the sender.

I use prepare for segue to capture this segue and set the `link` property of my destination `viewController`. However, when I cast the `sender` from `Any?` back to the tuple type, I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' to '(Swift.String, UIImage, Swift.String)'

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showAuthWindow" {
        let service = sender as! (name: String, image: UIImage, url: String)
        let authWindow = segue.destination as! AuthorisationViewController
        authWindow.link = service.url
    }
}
```

Please could somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Sender is not your data.  Sender is the object that initiated the segue (usually a button or a tableview or whatever).  Its pretty standard to ignore sender except when it makes a difference as to the view controller (it if you tap the add button the destination needs to know its in add mode as opposed to edit mode).  Use the selected index path to know what cell was tapped.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showAuthWindow" {
            guard let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else {
                return
            }
            let service = services[indexPath.item]
            let authWindow = segue.destination as! AuthorisationViewController
            authWindow.link = service.url
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already have a working alternative and understand the convention you have explained. However, the real purpose of asking this question is educational to understand why I can't cast back from `Any?` to tuple successfully in this case.